# using weka j48 in java code

Tags: java, weka

I am trying to use *Weka* in java code. I have successfully built the model for J48 and saved into the drive for testing purpose..however the output of classfiyinstance of a classifier is bound to one single value itself..any suggestions why is it so?

```
            build model function also works fine as it produces the evaluation summary which i have uploaded at the bottom
                public J48 buildModel() throws Exception {
                        J48 j48 = new J48();
                        j48.setMinNumObj(minNumObj);
                        j48.setConfidenceFactor(confidenceFactor);
                        j48.setNumFolds(numFolds);
                        j48.setUnpruned(unPruned);

                        fc.setClassifier(j48);
                        fc.buildClassifier(train);

                        Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(train);

                        evaluation.evaluateModel(fc, train);

                        System.out.println(evaluation.toSummaryString());
                        attribMap.modelResult = evaluation.toSummaryString();

                        return j48;
                    }
```

save model also works fine ,just added for reference

```
                    public void saveModel(J48 j48) throws Exception {
                        String fileName = attribMap.path + "\\" + attribMap.fileName;
                        System.out.println("j48 path:" + fileName);
                        fileName = fileName + "tem.model";
                        weka.core.SerializationHelper.write(fileName, j48);

                    }
```

this is test the model function to which the arff file path and model file path are sent

```
                    public String testModel(BufferedReader reader1, String modelPath, String classAtrib) {
                        double pred = 0.0;
                        try {
                            String result = "";
                            test = new Instances(reader1);
                            test.setClassIndex(test.numAttributes() - 1);
                            System.out.println("numattrib:" + test.numAttributes());
                            System.out.println("model path:" + modelPath);
                            J48 cls = (J48) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("H:\\C-DAC\\autoGeneratedFiles\\tem.model");
                            System.out.println(cls.toSummaryString());
                            System.out.println("test num instances:" + test.numInstances());
                            System.out.println("b4 pred: " + test.instance(0));
                            Evaluation eTest = new Evaluation(test);
                            double[] d = eTest.evaluateModel(cls, test);
                            for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                                System.out.println("val " + d[i]);
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < test.numInstances(); i++) {
                                System.out.println(", predicted: " + "pred value" + pred + "::::" + test.classAttribute().value((int) pred));

                            }
                            System.out.println("af pred:" + pred);
                            result = test.classAttribute().value((int) pred);
                            attribMap.modelTestResult = "Predicted value for " + classAtrib + " is " + result + "for the given inputs of ";
                            return result;

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("PR`enter code here`EDDD : " + pred + " " + test.numInstances());

                        }
                        return null;
                    }
```

Here the output will be generated but the pred variable always sticks onto one single value

here is the arff file that i am trying to test 
        Train Data
                @relation j48

```
            @attribute category_name {OBC,GEN,SC,ST}
            @attribute gender numeric
            @attribute paper numeric
            @attribute state_permanent numeric
            @attribute age numeric

            @data
            OBC,1,11,2,0.01
            GEN,2,11,35,0.01
            OBC,2,11,21,0.01
            OBC,2,5,32,0.01
            OBC,2,17,16,0.01
            GEN,2,5,34,0.01
            SC,2,8,21,0.01
            GEN,1,11,20,0.01
            OBC,1,5,12,0.01
            OBC,1,10,18,0.01
            GEN,2,10,2,0.01
            GEN,1,14,16,0.01
            OBC,2,17,17,0.01
            OBC,2,17,21,0.01
            OBC,2,17,32,0.01
            SC,1,8,32,0.01
```

This summary is for the for training data

```
        evaluation summary 
        Correctly Classified Instances         362               53.4712 %
        Incorrectly Classified Instances       315               46.5288 %
        Kappa statistic                          0.1393
        Mean absolute error                      0.2959
        Root mean squared error                  0.3846
        Relative absolute error                 93.3196 %
        Root relative squared error             96.654  %
        Coverage of cases (0.95 level)         100      %
        Mean rel. region size (0.95 level)      92.9838 %
        Total Number of Instances              677
```

Here is Test Data that is being given to the model,Hence i used test.numattributes-1 as my last attribute is the class attribute

```
       @relation j48


            @attribute gender numeric
            @attribute paper numeric
            @attribute state_permanent numeric
            @attribute age numeric
      @attribute category_name {OBC,GEN,SC,ST}

            @data
            1,11,2,0.01,?

         This is test data where ? tends to be the value that model has to predict but the problem is model is predicting the same value for any given input
```

Comment: Can you please clearly state the question?

Comment: the question is,the model is predicting the same class output value for any given test case.

Comment: Which one is your class attribute in the test file?

Comment: category  is the class attribute

Comment: But then aren't you setting age as your class attribute in the code? 3rd line inside try in testModel() method? Correct me if I am wrong.